# (End)User level access to objects in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are facing a use case where we need to store **confidential** images of the user on S3. Now as S3 is accessible over HTTP and if we give a read access to the objects they will be available to the world via web. We need to restrict the images/files only to that user. So the possible solutions we thought are:

1. URL masking in some way.(No idea exactly how)
2. storing the files/images by creating unique encrypted s3 keys

   eg: `http://bucket.s3.amazon.com/clients/img/j84jaljvkeh774d/myimage.jpg`

In the first one we may not get the cloudfront or cdn benefits as it might involve a independent proxy server.

The second one,is in a way secure as it would be difficult to predict the keyname,if its unique to a user.

Using **ACl and bucket policies** won't completely solve the problem. 
Also,if we write a policy which restricts IP addresses, the mobile app which uses the same API backend would end up not working as those would have requests originating from different IP's.

We know we cannot completely secure them,but do we have an approach to deal with such a scenario?Please share your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved by option one.

1. Disable the public access of files from S3 management console on AWS.
2. You only need to build expiring urls if you want to restrict access.
3. I suppose there must be a unique key available for each user. You can generate signed URLs using that key. for each object programmatically. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) is one example available for reference.

Comment: we don't want to go the signed url way as it has the overhead of creating and managing them. We are not sharing URL's across users,just want them to be exclusive to the users

Answer (score 2):

You want to use **[presigned URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)** for this. You generate those for a fixed (short) period of time, for a specific user. If this URL gets leaked, it doesn't matter – because they expire.

If you do that, everything in your bucket can remain private.

If you're using Ruby, here's a glimpse how you'd do this: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby/commit/f946c113ff24d97673d8ffd43cb4012c8e211992

Comment: The object is going to be there permanently, and generating and maintaining urls would be a different task.Does the SDK manage it internally(generating a signed url on every request?).Can you point to an example.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, you'd have to do this yourself. But yes, the object is kept permanently. Just the URL to make it accessible is created on-the-fly.

Comment: We do not want to share the url.We just want to access it within the application.Signed url's are a better fit for file sharing use cases.We need to display it within the application on users dashboard.Just we don't want it to be accessed or available across users,incase the url of the files are predictable.I hope I am clear.

Comment: Yes, I am aware you want to show it "internally", i.e. on a dashboard. It's good practice (we use it e.g. for invoice download). For sharing, signed URLs don't make much sense anyway – because you never know when the recipient opens that mail with the link, it might be expired by then ;-)